# Mercurial internals : Git subrepository status after aggressive permission change

Tags: git, mercurial, internals, mercurial-subrepos

**Disclaimer** : I'm not asking for a solution, a workaround or any kind of advice on how to do things, I'm just curious about the internals of Mercurial.

I have a mercurial repository with some subrepository in it (Git and Mercurial).

1. My repository  and all subrepo are in a clean state (ie: `hg st -S` returns nothing).
2. I do some aggressive permission changes at the root : `chown www-data:www-data -R *`

Now, `hg st -S` returns each and every file of the Git subrepos (the Mercurial ones are still considered "clean") as modified. The output of `hg diff -S -g` is empty. I was wondering why this happened ?

What I've discovered so far :

1. If I do a `git status` in one of the subrepo, the command show no pending modification and this particular repo isn't marked as modified by `hg st` anymore
2. If I limit the permission changes to a subrepo, only this subrepo is marked as modified (ie the "problem" isn't linked to the state of a file in the `.hg` directory)
3. Doing a clean update (`hg up -C`) "solves" the issue
4. If I change the permission only in the `.git` directory the subrepo is still considered clean
5. The output of `hg --debug up -C` differs for a Git subrepo marked as modified :

"clean" git subrepo :

```
subrepo/git1: git config --bool core.bare 
subrepo/git1: git rev-parse HEAD
subrepo/git1: git diff-index --quiet HEAD
```

"modified" git subrepo :

```
subrepo/git2: git config --bool core.bare
subrepo/git2: git rev-parse HEAD
subrepo/git2: git diff-index --quiet HEAD
  subrepo subrepo/git2: other changed, get git://github.com/XXXX/YYYY.git:6f2442d36bb44724af116b97c85d2e344fc9a0a2:git
subrepo/git2: git cat-file -e 6f2442d36bb44724af116b97c85d2e344fc9a0a2
subrepo/git2: git config --bool core.bare
subrepo/git2: git rev-parse HEAD
subrepo/git2: git reset HEAD
subrepo/git2: git reset --hard HEAD
```

So, as far as I can tell, the permission changes in the metadata isn't the cause here, so what is ? I'm probably just missing something really simple.

FYI, I use the 1.9.3 version and I don't remember if I remarked the same comportment on a previous one.

And before someone propose that I stop doing the permission change like this, I already did and I'm not confronted to this problem anymore, it's just that I like to understand why something is happening ;)

#### Update

running `git diff-index HEAD` gives the following output :

```
[...]
:100644 100644 fef0f187a5eabc82dc1a90661bd86d317114e40e 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M      my/file/insubrepo.php
[...]
```

If I run `git diff-index -p HEAD`, the diff is empty. I still have no clue why git consider these files modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The likely problem (with a potential solution):**

Changing the file mode will change the file stat with respect to the Git index (as noted [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/False-positives-in-git-diff-index-tp5869013p5891295.html)).

To correct the problem try:

1. Navigating to your Git sburepo
2. Run `git update-index --refresh`

That should fix the file stat being dirty.

---

**Background info on Mercurial internals:**

To determine if a Git subrepo is dirty (i.e. has local modifications), Mercurial runs `git diff-index --quiet HEAD`.

See the [`dirty`](http://www.selenic.com/repo/hg/file/351a9292e430/mercurial/subrepo.py#l844) method of [`subrepos.py::gitsubrepo`](http://www.selenic.com/repo/hg/file/351a9292e430/mercurial/subrepo.py#l705).

I expect that after you change permissions, `git diff-index` shows the changes that your manual execution of `git status` does not.

The output of `git diff-index` is formatted as follows (see [man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-diff-index.html#_raw_output_format) for details):

```
:<mode before> <mode after> <status> <file>
```

Given the output you listed above, this says that: "File `my/file/insubrepo.php` has been modified in the working copy, but the file mode is the same".

Comment: `git diff-index HEAD` show some changes, but I can't grasp what they means... I updated the question with a snapshot

Comment: Thank you for the research you put in that :) My "need to know" is satisfied !