# Symfony bin/vendors local modifications

Tags: git, symfony, vendors

I'm trying to install a new Symfony project without vendors preinstalled. I'm running Windows and i have used the following guide from the Symfony cookbook:

[How to Create and store a Symfony2 Project in git](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html)

I'm fairly new to both Git and Symfony. When i run the bin/vendors script i eventually run into this:

```
Installing/Updating monolog
M src/Monolog/Handler/FingersCrossed/ActivationStrategyInterface.php
M src/Monolog/Handler/FingersCrossed/ErrorLevelActivationStrategy.php
"monolog" has local modifications. Please revert or commit/push them before running this command again.
```

I'm running 2.0.15. I have tried (with the best of my limited knowledge on Git, cmd and Symfony) to fix this using this guide [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings) and eventually this [Charles Baily's answer to 'Trying to fix line-endings with git filter-branch, but having no luck'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510798/trying-to-fix-line-endings-with-git-filter-branch-but-having-no-luck/1511273#1511273).

I don't think I am doing it right though. I run the following lines from my cmd:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
#Nothing appears, just a new line

git rm --cached -r .
#Alot of files appear

git reset --hard
#HEAD is now at xxxxx initial commit

git add .
#According to the first link and Charles Baily's answer there should appear alot of files, but none do.

git commit -m "message"
#Nothing to commit
```

Does anybody have any clue to what I am doing wrong and how to fix this??

Comment: `cd` into *vendor/monolog* and do a `git reset --hard master`. Does that work?

Comment: I meant `origin/master`.

Comment: This did not work. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is with eol being automatically modified, then

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

would be a better config, done before any other git operations.
See "[Definitive recommendation for `git autocrlf` settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016673/definitive-recommendation-for-git-autocrlf-settings/2016763#2016763)" for the pros and cons.

Comment: Okay, so i started a new project - run the above command before my git init->add->commit and then i ran bin/vendors install, but still same error?

Comment: @Esben then those local modifications aren't only due to eol conversions. The .gitignore that you must create at the beginning of the process should take care of local *private* modifications (ie those which shouldn't be versioned). Check what `git diff-index --quiet HEAD` returns (as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170240/mercurial-internals-git-subrepository-status-after-aggressive-permission-chang).

Comment: I've gotten a new computer and had to reinstall Git. I noticed the CRLF option in the installation and set it to false (don't know what i had before). Since this the vendors script have been running perfectly, so i'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you may solve your problem:

1. Go to the monolog directory

   > cd vendor/monolog
2. Understand what you changed (optional step)

   > git diff
3. Cancel your modifications

   > git checkout .

Comment: This might work - solved my problem by other means. Se comment in VonC's answer. This could work for others, so thanks for the suggestion!